# Innodb fulltext increase speed

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I have field with fulltext index

This field contains only numbers with spaces like `2 3 44 52`, I use such search

`match(field) against ('+2 +52')`

Is it possible to increase speed of searching, without normalize table?

Answer (score 0):

I would review [MySQL's recommendations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-optimize) on maintaining innodb fulltext indexes.

Moreover, if the table is heavy `DELETE`, there is [a known performance bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86460) that causes query time to degrade over time.